Sci fi book where the President's consciousness is transferred into an android
It was a novel with a female protagonist who wakes up in a hospital at the very end. The entire thing is set on Mars, and there aren't any Martians. The big twist is that the President is immortal because he transferred his consciousness into an android (or potentially multiple androids, my memory's not clear on that one). The President and the politically powerful families are very rich, but the girl is not. There also may have been something about a couple families owning most of Earth, but I'm not sure about that either.

Hi, welcome to SF&F.  When did you read this?  How does the girl interact with the President?  What does she do, or what happens to her, that she ends up in hospital?
